# How to Copy PyObject*?

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

I am calling a Python Function from a C++ function like below.

```
void CPPFunction(PyObject* pValue)
{
  ...
  pValue = PyObject_CallObject(PythonFunction, NULL);
  ...
}

int main()
{
  PyObject *pValue = NULL;
  CPPFunction(PValue);
  int result_of_python_function = Pylong_aslong(PValue);
}
```

I would like to access the return value of python function outside the CPPFunction. since scope of PObject* returned by PyObject_CallObject is within CPPFunction, how to access the value outside CPPFunction?

Comment: save the address in a class member? or the bad way: have a global...(please don't)

Comment: What ever object returned by the function PyObject_CallObject has a lifetime within the CPPFunction only. In that case weather we return it or pass it to global variable, it doesnt make any change.  We cant access it. Am i right?

Comment: we can access it by returning the object memory location as pointer and creating new pointer in main function pointing to the same memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return it from the function like you would anywhere else.

```
PyObject* CPPFunction()
{
    // ...
    PyObject* pValue = PyObject_CallObject(PythonFunction, NULL);
    // ...
    return pValue;
}

int main()
{
  PyObject *value = CPPFunction();
  int result_of_python_function = Pylong_aslong(value);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and mine? both are same isn't it?

Comment: @Kumar No, they're not. `void CPPFunction(PyObject* pValue)` is not the same as `PyObject* CPPFunction()`.

Comment: My doubt is that the value returned by PyObject_CallObject has a lifetime within CPPFunction. So even if we copy it to pointer or return it , we cant access that variable outside its scope. isn't?

Comment: @Kumar The lifetime of the *variable* that the returned pointer is stored in is limited to `CPPFunction`'s scope. If you don't destroy the object it points to, you can safely return a pointer to that object, i.e. a copy of the returned pointer.

Answer (score 0):

make following changes and u can access the return value of python function outside the CPPFunction.Hope this helps:

```
PyObject* CPPFunction(PyObject* PythonFunction) // changes return type from void to PyObject and pass PythonFunction to be called
{
  pValue = PyObject_CallObject(PythonFunction, NULL);
  return pValue;
}

int main()
{
   PyObject *pValue = NULL;
   pValue = CPPFunction(PythonFunction); // assign return value from CPPFunction call to PyObject pointer pvalue
   long int result_of_python_function = Pylong_aslong(PValue);// data type changed from int to long int
   cout << result_of_python_function << endl; // just printing the python result
}
```